# jQuery - If ( "A" left value is equal to "B" width minus "C" width )

Tags: jquery, width, attr

Title says it well:

If ( `element-A`'s left value is equal to `element-B`'s width minus `element-C`'s width )

http://jsfiddle.net/UAKXq/1

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is correct

```
if (parseInt(A.css('left')) == B.width() - C.width()) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UAKXq/14/

Comment: Only problem is A.css('left') will return `200px`, so the integer needs to be extracted, using `parseInt('200px')`.

Comment: @Lollero: you've got plus there. please refresh my answer

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
if(parseInt(A.css('left')) == (B.width() - C.width()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( parseInt(A.css('left'),10) === parseInt(B.css('width'), 10) - parseInt(C.css('width'), 10)) { 
    $('body').css({ background: 'red' }); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UAKXq/20/